# Set a variable as column range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range for an entire column named DAY.
I have a macro that sets pagebreaks every time a cell's value in the DAY column changes (when changing from day 1, to day 2, or day 3, there will be a page break for printing).

The macro specifies the column by letter, like "A" or "B" or "C" or "H".
How can I specify the "DAY" named range so if it moves, the code doesn't break?

Attention to:

```
For Each c In Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
```

I want to change `Range("C1:C"`to `Range("DAY"`.

This breaks in various syntax forms I tried.

```vb
Sub Set_PageBreaks_DAY()
    Dim lastrow As Long, c As Range
    Dim i As Integer, rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("DAY", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
    For Each c In Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> c.Value And c.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem if DAY changes to column B's location, code breaks

Comment: it doesn't work, JLILI

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to note that Named ranges have 2 possible scopes which will affect how to access it.  If your named range has workbook scope, then you should use

```
Dim Named_range_day as Range
Set Named_range_day = ThisWorkbook.Names("Day").RefersToRange
```

If the named range has worksheet scope, then use

```
Dim Named_range_day as Range
Set Named_range_day = wksht.Names("Day").RefersToRange
```

where `wksht` is the worksheet variable for the worksheet containing the named range.

Answer (score 0):

The reason JLILI Aman's answer didn't work is you have to convert the column index number to a column letter first using

```
columnLetter = Split(Columns(i).Address(), "$")(2)
```

So for example

```
Sub Set_PageBreaks_CREW()

Dim lastrow As Long, c As Range
Dim i As Integer, rngData As Range
Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("DAY", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
columnLetter = Split(Columns(i).Address(), "$")(2)
Var = columnLetter & "1:" & columnLetter

For Each c In Range(Var & lastrow)
    If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> c.Value And c.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        c.Offset(1, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("DAY").Resize(lastrow,1)
```

The above will reference the cell with name `DAY` and `lastrow` rows below it and in one column.

In general to reference a table of 100 rows and 5 columns with the top left at a cell, for example `G2` use

```
Range("G2").Resize(100,5)
```

the above is entirely equivalent to

```
Range("G2:K101")
```

buy you don't have to do any of the weird string math with `Range("G2:K" & count+1)` etc.